# How to create/edit a weapon in ut2004's unrealed?

Tags: unreal, editors

I've searched a lot, but almost all of the ut2k4 Unrealed tutorial websites/blogs have disappeared. How do I create or edit a weapon in Unrealed?

Comment: Believe this would be considered off topic.  Questions here are for game design (level design, gameplay, mechanics, etc), asset pipelines (creation, storage, editing, etc), game-specific programming issues (engine architecture, game-related APIs, networking, tools, etc), project management (testing, team management, scheduling, publishing, etc), and game industry (careers, trends, technology, etc)

Comment: Mod making is definitely on topic.

Comment: @Tetrad noted. Guess that would fall under game-specific programming issues.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where to ask it. In game.stackexchnge they told me to come here

Comment: Is there a game actually called ut2004's unrealed? Is that not the same as UT2004 Unreal?

Comment: UnrealEd is the name of the editor.